# loop multiple arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:
[objet and arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc35U.png)

I would like to determine if the object has an array with values ​​and if so, save those values ​​by saving those values ​​in another arryar that I will then go through, I have the following up to now:

```
if (resp.Boutique.length >= 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < resp.Boutique.length; index++) {
        this.general.push(resp.Boutique[index]);
    }
}



if (resp.Curso.length >= 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < resp.Curso.length; index++) {
        this.general.push(resp.Curso[index]);
    }
}

if (resp.Deporte.length >= 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < resp.Deporte.length; index++) {
        this.general.push(resp.Deporte[index]);;
    }
}
```

but if you have more 'if' elements, I do not think it's the best way.

Any recommendation?

Comment: @valentinridriguez please paste your actual code rather than a picture of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If the properties always contain arrays, then there's no need to test for their length before iterating over them; if they have length 0, no iterations will be performed, so nothing will be pushed to `this.general`.

But there's a better way - you can simply *spread* each possibly-empty array into `this.general`, in a single line:

```
this.general = [...resp.Boutique, ...resp.Curso, ...resp.Deporte];
```

If the properties of `resp` contain only the arrays you want to include in `.general`, then iterate over the `values` of `resp` instead:

```
this.general = [].concat(...Object.values(resp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.concat(arr1, arr2, arr3 ...)
```

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr1 = [4, 5, 6, 7];
let arr2 = [7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(arr.concat(arr1, arr2));
```